# Select first & last date in window

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm trying to select first & last date in window based on month & year of date supplied.

Here is example data:

```
F.rates
| id | c_id | date       | rate |
---------------------------------
| 1  | 1    | 01-01-1991 | 1    |
| 1  | 1    | 15-01-1991 | 0.5  |
| 1  | 1    | 30-01-1991 | 2    |
.................................
| 1  | 1    | 01-11-2014 | 1    |
| 1  | 1    | 15-11-2014 | 0.5  |
| 1  | 1    | 30-11-2014 | 2    |
```

Here is pgSQL SELECT I came up with:

```
SELECT c_id, first_value(date) OVER w, last_value(date) OVER w FROM F.rates 
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date), c_id 
             ORDER BY date ASC)
```

Which gives me a result pretty close to what I want:

```
| c_id | first_date | last_date  |
----------------------------------
| 1    | 01-01-1991 | 15-01-1991 |
| 1    | 01-01-1991 | 30-01-1991 |
.................................
```

Should be:

```
| c_id | first_date | last_date  |
----------------------------------
| 1    | 01-01-1991 | 30-01-1991 |
.................................
```

For some reasons `last_value(date)` returns every record in a window. Which giving me a thought that I'm misunderstanding how windows in SQL works. It's like SQL forming a new window for each row it iterates through, but not multiple windows for entire table based on YEAR and MONTH.

So could any one be kind and explain if I'm wrong and how do I achieve the result I want?

There is a reason why i'm not using MAX/MIN over GROUP BY clause. My next step would be to retrieve associated rates for dates I selected, like:

```
| c_id | first_date | last_date  | first_rate | last_rate  | avg rate |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1    | 01-01-1991 | 30-01-1991 | 1          | 2          | 1.1      |
.......................................................................
```

Comment: Btw, sorry for bad english. I'm trying my best to lear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your output to become grouped into a single (or just fewer) row(s), you should use simple aggregation (i.e. `GROUP BY`), if `avg_rate` is enough:

```
SELECT c_id, min(date), max(date), avg(rate)
FROM F.rates
GROUP BY c_id, date_trunc('month', date)
```

More about window functions in [PostgreSQL's documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

> But unlike regular aggregate functions, use of a window function does not cause rows to become grouped into a single output row — the rows retain their separate identities.
>
> ...
>
> There is another important concept associated with window functions: for each row, there is a set of rows within its partition called its **window frame**. Many (but not all) window functions act only on the rows of the window frame, rather than of the whole partition. **By default**, if `ORDER BY` is supplied then the frame consists of **all rows from the start** of the partition up **through the current row**, plus any following rows that are equal to the current row according to the `ORDER BY` clause. When `ORDER BY` is omitted the default frame consists of all rows in the partition.
>
> ...
>
> There are options to define the window frame in other ways ... See [Section 4.2.8](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) for details.

**EDIT**:

If you want to collapse (min/max aggregation) your data and want to collect more columns than those what listed in `GROUP BY`, you have 2 choice:

### The SQL way

Select min/max value(s) in a sub-query, then join their original rows back (but this way, you have to deal with the fact, that min/max-ed column(s) usually not unique):

```
SELECT c_id,
       min first_date,
       max last_date,
       first.rate first_rate,
       last.rate last_rate,
       avg avg_rate
FROM   (SELECT   c_id, min(date), max(date), avg(rate)
        FROM     F.rates
        GROUP BY c_id, date_trunc('month', date)) agg
JOIN   F.rates first ON agg.c_id = first.c_id AND agg.min = first.date
JOIN   F.rates last  ON agg.c_id = last.c_id  AND agg.max = last.date
```

### PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON`

[`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) is typically meant for this task, but highly rely on ordering (only 1 extremum can be searched for this way at a time):

```
SELECT   DISTINCT ON (c_id, date_trunc('month', date))
         c_id,
         date first_date,
         rate first_rate
FROM     F.rates
ORDER BY c_id, date
```

You can join this query with other aggregated sub-queries of `F.rates`, but this point (if you really need both minimum & maximum, and in your case even an average) the SQL compliant way is more suiting.

Comment: Yet I can't figure out how do i retrieve first and last date value in GROUP BY clause. And further associated rates with that dates.

Comment: @GeningD. use `min()` & `max()` on dates. What do you want to do with rates? In your example, there are 3 rate input values where you have one output row.

Comment: I've updated question, sorry i didn't think through.

Comment: @GeningD. I assumed `rate` does not depend on `date` (in your examples, they both constantly increasing) -- if that's a general rule, you could use min() & max() with `rate` too

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot, i spend around 4 hours trying to figure out how to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Windowing functions aren't appropriate for this. Use aggregate functions instead.

```
select 
    c_id, date_trunc('month', date)::date, 
    min(date) first_date, max(date) last_date
from rates
group by c_id, date_trunc('month', date)::date;
```

```
 c_id | date_trunc | first_date | last_date
------+------------+------------+------------
    1 | 2014-11-01 | 2014-11-01 | 2014-11-30
    1 | 1991-01-01 | 1991-01-01 | 1991-01-30
```

---

```
create table rates (
  id integer not null,
  c_id integer not null,
  date date not null,
  rate numeric(2, 1),
  primary key (id, c_id, date)
);

insert into rates values
(1, 1, '1991-01-01', 1),
(1, 1, '1991-01-15', 0.5),
(1, 1, '1991-01-30', 2),
(1, 1, '2014-11-01', 1),
(1, 1, '2014-11-15', 0.5),
(1, 1, '2014-11-30', 2);
```